# how to show the selected value from database in select box in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql, json, codeigniter

Here I have a select box where I want to show the value which is stored in the database that is in the JSON format. If the value is present, it shows the selected value, otherwise it shows the default option `Delete leads` option. It's not working properly.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <select class="form-control" id="spm" name="spm" required style="">>
        <option value=""> Delete Leads </option>
        <? 
            foreach($slct_optn as $slct_optns)
            {
                $slctoptn = json_decode($slct_optns['spam_management'],1);
                ?>
                <option value="7" <?php if($slctoptn['delete']==7) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?>>1 Week Older</option>
                <option value="30" <?php if($slctoptn['delete']==30) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?>>1 Month</option>
                <option value="60" <?php if($slctoptn['delete']==60) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?>>2 Month</option>
            <? }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: here the data in the table is in [{ delete:7 }] fomat. here i am going to show the value from last inserted id in the database.

Comment: Likely short tags are your issue. Do you have them enabled? You are alternating usage here. If you view source Id guess you have PHP in the output.

Comment: @ShwethaShetty you have an invalid json format there, the collection key should be enclosed in quotes like `[{"delete":7}]`

Comment: sir how to remove the braces([]) from this json format using codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could change the `$slctoptn['delete']` to `$slctoptn[0]['delete']` variable like this :

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <select class="form-control" id="spm" name="spm" required style="">>
        <option value=""> Delete Leads </option>
        <? 
            foreach($slct_optn as $slct_optns)
            {
                $slctoptn = json_decode($slct_optns['spam_management'],1);
                ?>
                <option value="7" <?php if($slctoptn[0]['delete']==7) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?>>1 Week Older</option>
                <option value="30" <?php if($slctoptn[0]['delete']==30) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?>>1 Month</option>
                <option value="60" <?php if($slctoptn[0]['delete']==60) {?> selected="selected" <? } ?>>2 Month</option>
            <? }
        ?>
    </select>
```

This will use the only `'delete'` array inside the `$slctoptn` parent array.